# jquery sortable not working with jquery-ui-1.7.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to sort a list of ul items and using `jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js` for the same, but getting the below error:

```
$(...).sortable is not a function.
```

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure you included every widget to make `sortable()` work correctly?

Comment: Please, provide your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an HTML/js snippet or a jsfiddle you have some points to check.

Check to have included the jQuery core library.

Check to have included `jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js` in your file after jQuery.

You are using a custom distro so check to have included the right dependencies (**these ar for jQuery UI 1.9.1**) to let [sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) works:

- UI Core
- Widget factory
- Mouse interation

Run your script inside [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to ensure that the DOM is fully loaded before to acess it.

> Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded

Comment: Hey Edward,

Thank for your quick response.

fyi, below are the jquery files i am having in my page:
jquery-1.4.2.min.js,

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js,

jquery.min.js,

jquery.colorbox.js,

jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js,

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>,

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>,

now a sortable div is working but it has prevented my colorbox to open a dialogue.

i am wondering if there is conflict for .sortable() function between any of jquery files.

is there..?

Comment: You have to include only one version of jQuery and jQuery UI, usually the last. Keep in mind that and refactor your page

Comment: Hey Edward,

The problem i was facing was resolved.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission and inclusion of your jquery files. Sometime for permission browser not able to read the file and gives error.